# flex - Simple parser gives error: fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer missed

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, yacc, lexer

I'm trying to implement a simple parser that calculates addition, subtraction, multiplication and division using fractional numbers. Fractional numbers in this form: nominatorfdenominator like this 2f3 4f6 9f4 etc. Parser should run on REPL mode. To compile and run:

```
lex lexer.l
yacc -d parser.y
cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -lm -o main
./main
```

flex code:

```
%{
  #include "y.tab.h"
  extern YYSTYPE yylval;
  #include <math.h>
  void to_int(char* num, int* arr);
%}

IDENTIFIER_ERROR [0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
COMMENT ";;".*   
VALUESTR \"(.*?)\"

%%

[ \t\f\v\n] { ; }

exit   { return KW_EXIT; }

"+"  { return OP_PLUS; }
"-"  { return OP_MINUS; }
"/"  { return OP_DIV; }
"*"  { return OP_MULT; }
"("  { return OP_OP; }
")"  { return OP_CP; }

(0)|([1-9]+"f"[1-9]*)    { to_int(yytext, yylval.INT_ARR); return VALUEF; }
[a-zA-Z_]([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) { strcpy(yylval.STR, yytext); return IDENTIFIER; } 
{COMMENT}    { printf("%s: COMMENT\n",    yytext); }
{IDENTIFIER_ERROR} { printf("%s: SYNTAX ERROR\n", yytext); exit(1); }
                     
. { printf("%s: SYNTAX ERROR\n", yytext); exit(1); }



%%

// fractional number taken as a string, converting it to: arr[0] = nominator, arr[0]  = nominator, arr[1] = denominator,
void to_int(char* num, int* arr) {
  char* nominator, *denominator;

  strcpy(nominator, num); // nominator contains whole number for now
  strtok_r(nominator, "f", &denominator);

  //printf ("lex: NUMS parsed as: %s  %s\n", nominator, denominator);

  arr[0] = atoi(nominator);
  arr[1] = atoi(denominator);

  //printf("lex: nom: %d denom: %d\n", arr[0], arr[1]);

}

int yywrap(){
  return 1;
}
```

yacc file:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <math.h>

  int yylex(void);
  void yyerror(char *str);

  void fractional_divide(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF);
  void fractional_multiply(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF);
  void fractional_sub(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF);
  void fractional_sum(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF);
%}


%token KW_EXIT

%token OP_PLUS OP_MINUS OP_DIV OP_MULT OP_OP OP_CP OP_COMMA

%union{
  int INTEGER;
  int INT_ARR[2];
  char STR[20];
};

%start START
%type<INT_ARR> EXP
%token <INT_ARR> VALUEF


%%

START : EXPLIST ;  

EXPLIST : EXP | EXPLIST EXP ;

EXP:    OP_OP OP_PLUS  EXP EXP OP_CP { fractional_sum($3, $4, $$); printf("> %d%c%d\n", $$[0], 'f', $$[1]); }
      | OP_OP OP_MINUS EXP EXP OP_CP { fractional_sub($3, $4, $$); printf("> %d%c%d\n", $$[0], 'f', $$[1]); }
      | OP_OP OP_DIV   EXP EXP OP_CP { fractional_divide($3, $4, $$); printf("> %d%c%d\n", $$[0], 'f', $$[1]); }
      | OP_OP OP_MULT  EXP EXP OP_CP { fractional_multiply($3, $4, $$); printf("> %d%c%d\n", $$[0], 'f', $$[1]); }

      | VALUEF { $$[0] = $1[0]; $$[1] = $1[1];} 

      | KW_EXIT { printf("exiting...\n"); return 0; } 
      ;



%%

void equalize_denominators(int* num1, int* num2) {
  num1[0] *= num2[1]; 
  num1[1] *= num2[1];

  num2[0] *= num1[1]; 
  num2[1] *= num1[1]; 
}

void fractional_sum(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF) {
  if (num1[1] != num2[1])
    equalize_denominators(num1, num2);

  RESULTF[0] = num1[0] + num2[0];
  RESULTF[1] = num2[1];
}

void fractional_sub(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF) {
  if (num1[1] != num2[1])
    equalize_denominators(num1, num2);

  RESULTF[0] = num1[0] - num2[0];
  RESULTF[1] = num2[1];
}

void fractional_divide(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF) {
  RESULTF[0] = num1[0] * num2[1];
  RESULTF[1] = num1[1] * num2[0];
}

void fractional_multiply(int* num1, int* num2, int* RESULTF) {
  RESULTF[0] = num1[0] * num2[0];
  RESULTF[1] = num1[1] * num2[1];
}

void yyerror(char *str) {
    printf("yyerror: %s\n", str);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


  if(argc == 1)
    yyparse();

  else {
    printf("Input error. Exiting...\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

sample output, first line is ok, but when I hit the enter after second line I get this error:

```
(+ 2f3 1f3)
result: 3f3
(* 2f1 2f6)
result: 4f6
fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer missed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message can occur in some specific circumstances involving the use of `yymore()` in the last token in the input, but probably the most common cause is memory corruption, which is what you've managed to do here.

It's likely that the issue is in `to_int`, where you do a `strcpy` whose destination is an uninitialised pointer:

```c
void to_int(char* num, int* arr) {
  char* nominator, *denominator;

  strcpy(nominator, num);  // FIXME nominator is uninitialised
```

It's actually not clear to me why you feel the need to make a copy of the argument `num`, since you are calling it with `yytext`. You're free to modify the contents of `yytext` as long as you don't write outside of its memory area. (The variable `yyleng` tells you how long `yytext` is.) Since `strtok` does not modify it's argument outside of the contents area, it's safe to apply to `yytext`. But if you are going to copy `num`, you obviously have to copy it to an actual validly initialized pointer; otherwise chaos will ensue. (Which could include triggering random flex error messages.)

I didn't check your code thoroughly nor did I attempt to run it, so there may be other errors. In particular, I did notice a couple of problems with your token patterns:

1. `(0)|([1-9]+"f"[1-9]*)` does not allow `10f2` or `2f103`, since you only allow integers written with digits `1` through `9`. It also allows `2f`, whose meaning is opaque to me, and your `to_int` function could blow up on it. (At best, it would end up with a denominator of 0, which is also an error.) I'd recommend using two patterns, one for integers and the other for fractions:

   ```
   0|[1-9][0-9]* { yylval.INT_ARG[0] = atoi(yytext);
                   yylval.INT_ARG[1] = 1;
                   return VALUEF;
                 }
   0|[1-9][0-9]*f[1-9][0-9]* {
                   to_int(yytext, yylval.INT_ARR);
                   return VALUEF;
                 }
   ```

   But you might want to add more meaningful error messages for illegal numbers like `03f2` and `3f0`.
2. Although you don't use it anywhere, your pattern for character strings is incorrect, since (f)lex does not implement non-greedy matching. A better pattern would be `\"[^"]*\"` or `\"[^"\n]*\"` (which prohibits newlines inside strings); even better would be to allow backslash escapes with something like `\"(\\.|[^"\\\n])*\"`. There are lots of other variants but that basically covers the general principle. (Some of us prefer `["]` to `\"` but that's just stylistic; the meaning is the same.)

Also, it is bad style to call `exit` from a `yylex` action. It's better to arrange for some kind of error return. Similarly, you should not use a `return` statement from a `yyparse` action, since it leaves the parser's internal state inconsistent, and does not allow the parser to free the resources it has allocated. Use `YY_ACCEPT` (or `YY_ABORT` if you want to signal a syntax error). These are described in the documentation or any good guide.